How to view a generic list of local history as opposed to only a list of history per item
If I right click on my database in explorer pane and go to Local History, the list of results just shows me the changes I've made to whatever object I've got open in the main area (such as a specific stored procedure).
I want to be able to see a list that will tell me what Stored Procedures have been amended today, yesterday, and so on (and tables altered, if possible).
Sort of a UI equivalent to SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY modify_date DESC

We have a feature to compare object changes like local versioning, but not the audit
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/modifying-source-code-of-database-objects.html#see-the-diff-between-modified-and-stored-versions
I have created this feature request on our tracker where you can upvote
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/modifying-source-code-of-database-objects.html#see-the-diff-between-modified-and-stored-versions

Thank you. Both your links went to the documentation. Here's the link to the tracker item: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-20811/Audit-changes-made-to-database-objects-in-MSSQL - I've added some comments to it, and added my vote
